# Import directory errors with Python 3.5 and above

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path, absolute-path, sys.path

I want to import modules from folder and subfolder with Python 3.6. 
Currently I have a structure like this.

```
└── project
    │   main.py
    ├── package1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── module1.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module2.py
```

When I import module1 and module2, I have no problem with that.
Within `main.py` having this scripts to import both modules.

```
from package1 import module1
from package2 import module2
```

It works fine!

But I want to move package2 with module2 into a subfolder under package1 as shown below:

```
└── project
    │   main.py
    └── package1
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1.py
        └── subpackage1
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── module2.py
```

And want to call module2 from `main.py`. Having tried following path and scripts does not fix my problem I get import error, it can not find the path.

Within `main.py` having this scripts to import both modules.

```
from package1.subpackage1 import module2
```

or

```
from package1.subpackage1.module2 import Class_in_module2
```

or

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
from package1.subpackage1 import module2
```

It does not work. Path can not be found! 
Any help appreciate!

Comment: After you moved I don't See package1 in the tree which you showed , may be you might have missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the **from** keyword accepts an hierarchy of folders and **import** the specific method from the file, this should work.

```
from MainFolder.SubFolder.SomeDotPy import foo,bar,somevalue
```